# Definition of non measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

A set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called measurable if $\forall B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \colon \mu(B) = \mu(B \cap A) + \mu(B\backslash A)$, where $\mu$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is therefore not measurable if $\exists B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \colon \mu(B) < \mu(B \cap A) + \mu(B\backslash A)$, since $\mu$ is monotone with respect to inclusion. The name ''non measurable'' suggests that we can't ''compute'' the volume of a set. This suggestion also makes sense if we talk about the vitali set $P$. There one shows that $\mu(P)= \mu([0,1])=1$ and $\mu(P)=0$ or $\mu(P)=\infty$. Therefor the vitali set has no reasonable volume. Now, from this observation that there are sets which we can't assign a volume (otherwise we have a contradiction), how does one come up with the standard definition of measurability which I presented above?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: You show there exist sets that can't be assigned a measure, otherwise you get a contradiction (example:  vitali set). Based on this what is the motivation for the definition of mesurability?

Comment: The above definition only makes sense for an outer measure. The motivation is precisely what the statement is, that we regard a set to be measurable with respect to an outer measure if it splits an arbitrary set additively.

Comment: @copper.hat Terminology varies.    What you and I call an  "outer measure" is called a "measure" by Federer.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the clarification. I have been tripped up more than once by the time varying nature of some definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Statement of this in a notation I prefer ...

> A set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called $\mu^*$-**measurable** iff $\forall B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \colon \mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B\backslash A)$, where $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.

This definition is due to Carathéodory.

Carathéodory's reasoning for the definition is known (see his personal notes given in his collected works).  For Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R$, the condition for measurability given by Lebesgue could be stated

> A set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is called **Lebesgue measurable** iff
> for all bounded intervals $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap A) +\mu^*(B\backslash A)$, where $\mu^*$ is
> Lebesgue outer measure.

Carathéodory was trying to generalize to outer measures $\mu^*$ in $\mathbb R^n$ where all intervals have infinite outer measure, so Lebesgue's formulation was useless.  He came up with the idea to use **all** subsets, not just the intervals.  In cases where bounded intervals have finite measure, we can show Carathéodory's definition agrees with Lebesgue's.

An example, already given by Carathéodory, is: "arc length" measure in $\mathbb R^n$, with $n \ge 2$.

---

In Lebesgue's case, when our set $A$ is bounded, we take a large "interval" (in $n>2$ a hypercube) $B \supseteq A$.  Then we define **inner measure** $\mu_*(A) =  \mu^*(B) - \mu^*(B\setminus A)$.  The equation
$\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap A) +\mu^*(B\backslash A)$ then tells us exactly that the inner measure of $A$ equals the outer measure of $A$. This is the concept Lebesgue started with.