# Why pick this definition of measurability over this almost identical one?

Tags: measure-theory

In our measure theory classes, we are going through the construction of measures from outer measures (any $\sigma$-additive monotonic function on a power set). In that, the following definition of measurability is thrown at us out of the blue:

> Given an outer measure $\pi^*$ on a set $X$, a subset $A\subseteq X$ is called measurable iff for every $E\subseteq X$, we have
> $$
> \pi^*(E) = \pi^*(E\cap A) + \pi^*(E\setminus A)\text.
> $$

Now, I could have demanded that for each $E$, $A$ gets partitioned such that $\pi^*(A) = \pi^*(A\cap E) + \pi^*(A\setminus E)$. But the above definition instead focuses on the partition of $E$ induced by $A$.

**Question:** Is there an "easy" way to "see" why measurability is not defined in this alternate way? Of course, I am not looking for an answer like, "It makes the proofs work.".

Comment: See my answer to another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4759386/442

Comment: @GEdgar That doesn't seem to help... :(

Answer (score 5):

A good example of a non-measurable set is a [Vitali Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) $Q \subseteq [0,1]$ such that the Lebesgue outer measure is $1$ and the inner measure is $0$.  That is,
$$
\mu^*(Q) = 1 , \qquad
\mu^*([0,1]\setminus Q) = 1
$$
In the usual definition, taking $A=Q, E=[0,1]$, we get
$1 \ne 1+1$ and this shows $Q$ is not measurable.

What about the proposed alternate definition?
Take $A = [0,1]$.  We have for $E=Q$ that $1 \ne 1+1$
and so we conclude that $[0,1]$ is **not measurable**.

[In fact, the only measurable sets we get are the sets of outer measure zero.]

Answer (score 3):

An outer measure can be thought of as an approximation of a measure from the "outside". In fact, we have the following result:

Suppose you are given a set $X$ and a collection $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $X$ containing $X$ and the empty set. If $\rho : \mathcal{C} \to [0, \infty]$ is such that $\rho(\emptyset) = 0$ then  $\mu^\ast : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0, \infty]$ given by
$$
\mu^\ast(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \rho(E_j) : A \subseteq \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}E_j\right\}
$$
is an outer measure.

Analogously, for any $E\subseteq X$, we can approximate the measure of a set $A\subseteq E$ from within $E$. Define the inner measure of a set $A\subseteq E$ with respect to $E$ to be $\mu_\ast(A) := \mu^\ast(E) - \mu^\ast(E\setminus A)$.

The set $A \subseteq E$ is "well-approximated" in $E$ provided that is has the same inner and outer measure. That is,
$$
\mu^\ast(E) = \mu_\ast(E) = \mu^\ast(E) - \mu^\ast(E\setminus A).
$$
Put otherwise,
$$
\mu^\ast(E) = \mu^\ast(A) + \mu^\ast(E\setminus A) = \mu^\ast(A\cap E) + \mu^\ast(E\setminus A).
$$
Measurable sets are those that can be well approximated everywhere, hence the definition.

Suppose now that you consider instead all those sets $A$ such that
$$
\mu^\ast(A) = \mu^\ast(A\cap E) + \mu^\ast(A\setminus E)
$$
for all $E$. Those are all the sets that can be arbitrarily subdivided while respecting additivity. However, think about what happens (see for instance the other answer) if $A$ is measurable and $E\subseteq A$ is not. Then you would be trying to subdivide $A$ into $E\cap A = E$ and $A\setminus E$. That is, you would be subdividing $A$ into two non-measurable sets!

More explanations found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability. To quote the link, a set is measurable if "you can make change with it".

> make change, as in money. If you and your friend want to buy a set $S$ that is quoted at a price $\mu^\ast(S)$, but you really only want a subset of $A$ and your friend only wants a subset of $A^\complement$, then you can "pay" $\mu^\ast(S\cap A)$ and your friend $\mu^\ast(S\setminus A)$ and the seller will be happy. In a sense, $A$ is measurable when you and your friend know you can do that no matter the $S$.